# Any multi player capability for sphero api for android

Tags: sphero-api

I've read it's not possible for iOS, but it is possible to control more than 1 ball at a time for android. But nothing about using 2 or more balls with 2 or more devices in the same area.

We'd love to use 3-5 of them in the same area with 3-5 android devices controlling 1 ball apiece.

I take it, if you had 3 different versions of your app, one on each device, will they conflict with one another? I doubt you could see a character on each of the other balls you aren't controlling. But if they'd still work in the same space we might still go for it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.  Are you trying to do something like the game Tag?

[Sphero Tag](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.orbotix.tag)

Comment: Epic guys, thanks! We're looking to make more of a racing/obstacle competition with half a dozen+ at large events. With a course and stuff.

Comment: If you're looking for a good multiplayer library, we used PlayPhone for our Tag game.  The multiplayer game in TwoPhonesOneBall isn't as stable as PlayPhone's.  It will work though.

Answer (score 1):

Look though the SDK and you'll come across:
https://github.com/orbotix/Sphero-Android-SDK/tree/master/samples/TwoPhonesOneBall